# Find latest revision for non-unique account numbers

Tags: sql

I'm stuck trying to get some useful information out of a line-of-business system we're using. Essentially there's a table I want to use in order to query onother one, but before I can get that far I need to get the 'latest revision' version for an account.

The table is pretty big & seems poorly designed, but the 3 fields I'm currently interested in are Account, Revision & Display. Account is an account number, Revision and Display are integers (stored as text). NONE of thenm are unique, although the combination of Account & Revision is.
What I want to do is find the highest revision number for each account, & then use the associated Display to link to my other table(s). The SQL I've got so far is :

```
select account, revision, display
from histhead o
where revision = (
select max(revision) 
from histhead
where revision = o.revision)
```

Unfortunately, because there are multiple accounts of the same value it brings back something like :

```
account     revision    display
005598 001  201005      7843
005598 001  310358      17618
005598 002  201005      7844
005598 002  999999      17619
005598 003  201005      7845
005598 003  999999      17620
007475      200810      962
007475      200900      1252
007475      999999      16910
007641      201003      7039
007641      201311      25958
```

Whereas what I really want is just :

```
account     revision    display
005598 001  310358      17618
005598 002  999999      17619
005598 003  999999      17620
007475      999999      16910
007641      201311      25958
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that, please?

thanks

Mark

Comment: What kind of rdbms are you using(f.e MS SQL-Server, MySql, Oracle, ...)? Tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The query you want needs to be correlated on the account number:

```
select account, revision, display
from histhead hh
where revision = (select max(hh2.revision) 
                  from histhead hh2
                  where hh2.account = h.account
                 )
```

Comment: That seems to do exactly what I wanted!  Thanks very much for the extremely speedy response.  Mark